# Can't install vc_redist.x64 [Unknown Error]

Tags: c++, 64-bit, vcredist

Good evening everyone,

I'm currently having a hard time trying to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x64)

It all started when this error-message appeared for no reason.
[api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6sf2.png)

So I jumped into google and quickly found out my Laptop needs the current vc_redist update.
Sadly no matter what I try I always get the following error:
[0x80240017 - Unknown Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kKlW.png)

This error is bugging me for a long time already, I really hope you guys can help me any further.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Cheerz~

Comment: The Log contains the following output (Pastebin link since line-breaks are ignored by Stack-Overflow):

http://pastebin.com/QYz14LdB

Here you can see that I do have a x64 system, so I didn't grab the wrong vc_redist installer for sure.

https://i.gyazo.com/616d1e84a9ffb1d7912982fc6a5aa33c.png

Comment: For me, installing the latest Windows updates fixed the error during the installation of the redistributable package. Not sure if it was the same error code though.

Comment: Thanks alot @Robert , it solved my problem, you're my hero! :-)